# Derive Parent Record from Child records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, left-join

I have the following Data which look like below
table

```
+----------+-----------+-------------+
| Child_ID | Parent_ID | Identifier  |
+----------+-----------+-------------+
| C1       | p1        | IN          |
| C2       | p1        | OUT         |
| C1       | p2        | IN          |
| C2       | p2        | OUT         |
| C1       | p3        | IN          |
| C2       | p3        | OUT         |
+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

I need to output the data in such a way that I can display the parent record in a separate row linking the 2 child id based on the identifier.

Desired Result :

```
+----+-----------+---------+----------+------------+
| ID | Parent_ID | Child_1 | Child_2  | Identifier |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+------------+
| C1 | P1        | NULL    | NULL     | IN         |
| C2 | P1        | NULL    | NULL     | OUT        |
| P1 | NULL      | C1      | C2       | IN         |
| C1 | P2        | NULL    | NULL     | IN         |
| C2 | P2        | NULL    | NULL     | OUT        |
| P2 | NULL      | C1      | C2       | IN         |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+------------+
```

To achieve This I ran the following query where I tried to left join to separate parent record and then UNION to find child records.

```
-- Parent 
Select c1.PARENT_ID as ID,
       Parent_Id,
       c1.Child_ID as Child_1
       c2.Child_ID as Child_2
       c1.Identifier
from sampletable as c1
left join sampletable as c2
on c2.PARENT_ID = c1.PARENT_ID 
and c2.Identifier = 'OUT'
where c1.Identifier = 'IN'

UNION

-- CHILD
Select child_id as ID,
       Parent_id,
       CASE when Identifier = 'IN' then Child_ID
       Else NULL END As Child_1,
       CASE when Identifier = 'OUT' then Child_ID
       Else NULL END As Child_2,
       Identifier
from sampletable 
where parent_id is not null
```

---

Please can someone point out what am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the children as they are.

For the parents use a subquery in the `FROM`, to get the set of distinct `Parent_ID`s. Provided, that there are only two children you can use other subqueries selecting `min(Child_ID)` or `max(Child_ID)` respectively, in the column list.

`UNION ALL` both results.

Put an outer query over the result of the `UNION ALL` and order it by `coalesce(Parent_ID, ID), CASE WHEN ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, ID` to achieve that order you want. The `CASE` is a hack for ensuring, that `ID`s being `NULL` come last. (I'm not sure if `NULLS` come first or last in SQL Server and too lazy to look it up right now. Or there is an database wide option, if I recall correctly? Anyway, having it explicitly in the query is the safest bet.)

```
SELECT * 
       FROM (SELECT Child_ID ID,
                    Parent_ID,
                    NULL Child_1,
                    NULL Child_2,
                    Identifier
                    FROM sampletable
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT x.Parent_ID ID,
                           NULL Parent_ID,
                           (SELECT min(Child_ID)
                                  FROM sampletable y
                                  WHERE y.Parent_ID = y.Parent_ID) Child_1,
                           (SELECT max(Child_ID)
                                   FROM sampletable y
                                   WHERE y.Parent_ID = y.Parent_ID) Child_2,
                           'IN' Identifier
                           FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Parent_ID
                                        FROM sampletable) x) u
       ORDER BY coalesce(Parent_ID,
                         ID),
                CASE
                  WHEN ID IS NULL
                    THEN 1
                  ELSE
                    0
                END,
                ID;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8ecf6/4/0)